# Merge columns with the same value with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

It is possible merge columns with the same value in `awk`? Something like

```
if awk '$1 = $2' then merge
```

I got this

```
AZ14962 AZ14962 ctg_    104
AZ14962 AZ14962 ctg_    4
AZ14962 AZ14962 ctg_    61
AZ14962 AZ14962 ctg_    23
```

Expected output:

```
AZ14962 ctg_    104
AZ14962 ctg_    4
AZ14962 ctg_    61
AZ14962 ctg_    23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be quite simple:

```
awk '$1==$2{$2=""}1' file
```

First we test if first column is equal second (`$1==$2`) and if result is positive then delete second column (`$2=""`). Final `1` just prints everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying in the wrong way: `awk -F"\t" '{if($1=$2){print $1 }else{print $1, $2}}'`

Comment: @zorbax You can do it in long way too, just use double `==` in test condition, and you need to explicitly print all columns: `awk '{if($1==$2){print $1,$3,$4}else{print $1,$2,$3,$4}}'`, or simpler: `awk '{if($1==$2){print $1,$3,$4}else{print $0}}'`